# Cleaning up FIND header information in batch file

Tags: batch-file, find

If I use FIND (WinXP) like this:

```
FIND /I "blahblah" test.txt > test2.txt
```

The first two lines are header information:

```
CRLF
---------- TEST.TXTCRLF
```

(The CRLF aren't visible of course).

Is there an easy/clever way to strip out those first two lines?

I'd prefer to do it natively without additional software, but could use a utility in a pinch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
findstr /i "blahblah" test.txt > test2.txt
```

Comment: Couldn't you at least have pretended it was hard? ;)  Thanks!